# Simple resistors, inductors first order circuit

Tags: inductor

Asuuming the following circuit has been turned on for a long time:
[image]

I need to find the current Il=current that goes through the inductor.
I know that the indoctor acts as a short circuit, but i still can't figure how to calculate the current.
I was thinking that all the current goes through the inductor, but that still doesn't make sense and doesn't help me solve.
Any tips/help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Here's a tip: You said that the inductor is short-circuit. Then you can remove the inductor and the 18 ohm resistor from the circuit, because the resistor is shorted. Re-draw the circuit and mark the place where the inductor was. Then calculate the current through that location.

Comment: I'm ignoring the 18ohm resistor, i still got a a set of resistors. the things is, that even if the inductor acts as short, current still has to go through the 4 ohm and the 3 ohm resistors, but i still can't figure out from here

Comment: Yes, the current will flow through the resistors. Also don't forget the 12 and 6 ohm resistors. You can use the rule for parallel resistors with them. Then you can use the Kirchoff's laws  to get a system of equations and current going through the 3 ohm resistor from them.

Comment: I calculated the total resistance of the system and got a current I=10.5A. I still don't understand why isn't this whole 10.5A curren't ain't the one going through the inductor, and what i should do to find it...

Comment: Did you re-draw the circuit with unneeded components removed? If so, you should notice that there are elements in series with the inductor which have some resistance. This will prevent all current from going through the short and you'll need to use regular math for the rest of the circuit.

Comment: Perhaps you can find a second grader with a box of crayons to draw the schematic more neatly for you.  Or even better, use the built-in schematic editor.

Comment: Do not use the mouse to hand-paint text; even Microsoft Paint (a "standard" utility installed on every Windows box) has a text tool. It's the box labelled "A".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the 3, 6 and 12 ohms resistors are in parallel (asuming the inductor is 0 ohms) - this means \${12 \over 7} ohms\$. Add the 4 ohms resistor and you got \$ {12 \over 7} + 4 = {40 \over 7} ohms\$. The current through this is \$60 \cdot {7 \over 40} = 10.5 A\$. Using this we calculate the voltage across the three resistors in parallel:

\$ {12 \over 7} \cdot 10.5 = 18 V\$. Then divide this by the 3 ohms resistor: \${18 V \over 3 ohms} = 6 A\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhr6ah.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>